# Matlab: Array of random integers with no direct repetition

Tags: matlab, random, replace, shuffle, sampling

For my experiment I have 20 categories which contain 9 pictures each. I want to show these pictures in a pseudo-random sequence where the only constraint to randomness is that one image may not be followed directly by one of the same category.
So I need something similar to

`r = randi([1 20],1,180);`

just with an added constraint of two numbers not directly following each other. E.g.

14     8    15    15     7    16     6     4     1     8   is not legitimate, whereas

14     8    15    7     15    16     6     4     1     8    would be.

An alternative way I was thinking of was naming the categories A,B,C,...T, have them repeat 9 times and then shuffle the bunch. But there you run into the same problem I think?
I am an absolute Matlab beginner, so any guidance will be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The following uses **modulo operations** to make sure each value is different from the previous one:

```
m = 20; %// number of categories
n = 180; %// desired number of samples
x = [randi(m)-1 randi(m-1, [1 n-1])];
x = mod(cumsum(x), m) + 1;
```

**How the code works**

- In the third line, the first entry of `x` is a random *value* between `0` and `m-1`. Each subsequent entry represents the *change* that, modulo `m`, will give the next value (this is done in the fourth line).
- The key is to choose that change between `1` and `m-1` (not between `0` and `m-1`), to assure consecutive values will be different. In other words, given a value, there are `m-1` (not `m`) choices for the next value.
- After the modulo operation, `1` is added to to transform the range of resulting values from `0`,...,`m-1` to `1`,...,`m`.

**Test**

Take all (`n-1`) pairs of consecutive entries in the generated `x` vector and count occurrences of all (`m^2`) possible combinations of values:

```
count = accumarray([x(1:end-1); x(2:end)].', 1, [m m]);
imagesc(count)
axis square
colorbar
```

The following image has been obtained for `m=20; n=1e6;`. It is seen that all combinations are (more or less) equally likely, except for pairs with repeated values, which never occur.

[image]

Comment: +1 I was just writing up an answer based on this.  Yours is cleaner than mine was shaping up to be.

Comment: Not completely sure of the theory, but checked with `hist` and the values are random indeed! Looks legit to me.

Comment: Yes, it's a little confusing :-) Just think that each entry of `x` in the third line is the term that will be added to the previous entry to obtain the current value. The values are lastly reduced modulo `m` into the desired interval

Comment: Wow! That'a a pretty interesting and useful graph for this problem! Kool!! Wish I had just more +1 to give on this!

Answer (score 1):

You could look for the repetitions in an iterative manner and put new set of integers from the same group `[1 20]` only into those places where repetitions have occurred. We continue to do so until there are no repetitions left -

```
interval = [1 20]; %// interval from where the random integers are to be chosen
r = randi(interval,1,180); %// create the first batch of numbers

idx = diff(r)==0; %// logical array, where 1s denote repetitions for first batch
while nnz(idx)~=0
    idx = diff(r)==0; %// logical array, where 1s denote repetitions for
                      %// subsequent batches
    rN = randi(interval,1,nnz(idx)); %// new set of random integers to be placed
                             %// at the positions where repetitions have occured
    r(find(idx)+1) = rN; %// place ramdom integers at their respective positions
end
```

Comment: +1 Your rejection method is clearer than mine, although its running time is random and possibly larger

Comment: @LuisMendo Yeah I would go for a no-loop solution, if I could make one!:)

Comment: I've added some test code. Of course your solution works equally well according to that test